# "Cannot run the macro" error after closing and reopening Workbook using macro

Tags: excel, vba

So I wrote a really simple bit of code that would essentially undo the changes done by another macro. The other macro saves the workbook, then copies data to another sheet and deletes the original data. The "Undo" script I've written simply closes and reopens the workbook without saving it - not fool proof I know but it's better than nothing. It runs perfectly fine and does what I want - but when it reopens the workbook I get the following warning message "Cannot run the macro 'OpenMe'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled." All my macros still work fine after the reopening. Here's the code I have for the close and open macro:

```
Sub Yes_Click()

Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "OpenMe"
ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub

Sub OpenMe()

MsgBox "Changes Undone"

End Sub

Sub No_Click()

Undo.Hide

End Sub
```

All I want is for this silly warning to not pop up! Any suggestions appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reopen the workbook, else you won't have any code to run:

```
Sub Yes_Click()

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "OpenMe"
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
Sub OpenMe()

    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim pth As String
    pth = wb.FullName

    Application.Workbooks.Open pth
    MsgBox "Changes Undone"

End Sub
Sub No_Click()

    Undo.Hide

End Sub
```

Comment: It already does reopen though? I have tested it and it does close and reopens the previous saved file... I mean I was confused myself, but it works

Comment: this is how it works for me, I'm using this code everytime I run a macro to close and reopen the workbook.

Comment: I tried your way - still get the same warning saying it cannot run the macro :/

Comment: Something is going on on your workbook, I did put the code on a workbook, deleted a sheet, run the  `Yes_Click` and the workbook reopenned with the sheet still there and the "Changes Undone" message.

Comment: Any idea as to what it would be? Because this is the first problem I've had - I don't see why it would be able to access all other macros but not the OpenMe() one

Comment: @JennThorpe did you try the code in a fresh new workbook? I did and it was working allright with everything on the same module.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution - I had to move the code for OpenMe() to a separate Module, then it all worked without a warning popping up :)